# Compiler Error MC3030: Owner Class of IEnumerable Property must Implement IAddChild

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, compiler-errors

I am trying to build a custom [`Panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) subclass in .NET 4.0 Client Profile. I started out like this:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
    }
}
```

This can be nicely integrated with some child controls in XAML (`local` being the prefix for the namespace in which `MyPanel` resides):

```
<local:MyPanel>
    <Button/>
    <CheckBox/>
</local:MyPanel>
```

Now, I would like to add a collection property to `MyPanel`. Hence, I extend the class:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
    }

    private readonly List<Button> someList = new List<Button>();

    public IList<Button> SomeList {
        get {
            return someList;
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good, the XAML code from above still compiles.

However, I would like to add some elements to the `SomeList` property right there, in XAML, so I write:

```
<local:MyPanel>
    <local:MyPanel.SomeList>
        <Button/>
    </local:MyPanel.SomeList>
    <Button/>
    <CheckBox/>
</local:MyPanel>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile any more, as the compiler outputs the following error:

> Bei der Eigenschaft "SomeList" handelt es sich um eine schreibgeschützte IEnumerable-Eigenschaft. Das bedeutet, dass "IAddChild" von "MyNamespace.MyPanel" implementiert werden muss. Zeile 9 Position 4. (MC3030)

In English (according to [Unlocalize](http://unlocalize.com/ko/8262_MC3030-x0-property-is-a-read-only-IEnumerable-property-which-means-that-x1-must-implement-IAddChild.html)):

> MC3030: 'SomeList' property is a read-only IEnumerable property, which means that 'MyNamespace.MyPanel' must implement IAddChild.

Apparently, this refers to the [`System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iaddchild%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Not a problem, doesn't seem too complicated - so, I implement `IAddChild` in `MyPanel` (for a start in a way that doesn't do anything useful, but that shouldn't matter as the methods will not be executed before the application as compiled):

```
public class MyPanel : Panel, IAddChild
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
    }

    private readonly List<Button> someList = new List<Button>();

    public IList<Button> SomeList {
        get {
            return someList;
        }
    }

    public void AddChild(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void AddText(string text)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This should work, but ... **no, it doesn't!** I am still getting the same error MC3030 when compiling.

**I did exactly as the error message indicated, and yet, the error does not go away. Am I missing any other modification that the compiler keeps secret from me?**

The [documentation on `IAddChild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iaddchild%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not seem to mention anything relevant for this situation. Moreover, googling for *MC3030* connected to either `IAddChild` or `WPF` just brings up the [aforementioned Unlocalize entry](http://unlocalize.com/ko/8262_MC3030-x0-property-is-a-read-only-IEnumerable-property-which-means-that-x1-must-implement-IAddChild.html) as the only related result. Apparently, error MC3030 is an *extremely* obscure error that very few developers have encountered so far.

Answer (score 1):

That issue occurs because the property is exposed as a generic collection type. If you change the property type from `IList<Button>` to `IList`, the error should go away. You might also want to consider setting the designer serialization visibility to content if the property represents a collection that will eventually have some visible effect in the designer.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public IList SomeList
{
    get
    {
        return someList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is not ideal, but I think the only way to work with generic collections from xaml involves creating your own markup extension (such as what is discussed in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/limitedgenericssupportinxaml.aspx)). However, since the property is backed by a generic collection, you will get an exception if you try to put the wrong thing in there.

Comment: Then why does it work for built-in types, such as for the [`ColumnDefinitions` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columndefinitions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a [`Grid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. To my knowledge, none of the built in types  used in XAML are generic collections. They are always specialized. The property you mentioned is a `ColumnDefinitionCollection` not a `List<ColumnDefinition>`.

Comment: Well, [`ColumnDefinitionCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinitioncollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does implement [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (though it does also implement [`IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).